# .Net lib to control remote GDB

Tags: c#, .net, gdb, protocols

I'm interested in createing Visual frontend to GDB. So I'm interested is there any library to handle **remote protocol** of **GDB** from **.Net**.

I think WPF will make good UI frontend.

Comment: You probably mean the GDB MI protocol.  The remote protocol is a low-level thing for talking to gdbserver.  I don't know offhand if there is such a library in C# (I know of ones in C, C++, and Python); but if I were looking I would start by checking to see if MonoDevelop has one.