# How you integrate a C++ compiler into a C# app?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++11, gcc

I want to make an app in C#(.NET) where you will have ,let's say a richtextbox,where you can write C++ code and a button for debugging and running the app which is written in richtextbox ! How to do that ? How can I integrate C++ compiler (`G++ 5.3.0 C++0X ENABLED` for example) into my app to run that ? I know that for sites it could be use [Ideone Api](https://ideone.com/sphere-engine) ! I can get the compiler from `MinGW/bin` !

Comment: Is [Google](https://www.google.co.in/) down?

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I didn't find anything relevant :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to start C++ compiler like any other external process:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"path\to\gcc";
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-Wall myFile.cpp"; //argument
pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //not diplay a windows
pProcess.Start();
string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
int exitCode = pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Then analyze output/exit code to see if there was any errors.

There will be much more trouble with debugger (e.g. gdb - because it has fully command line interface), you can send commands using StandardInput property of `Process` class, but it will be rather complicated. As you can see [.Net lib to control remote GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250572/net-lib-to-control-remote-gdb) there is no library for this yet.

Comment: So i get this error : `Additional information: Access is denied` ! the folder with complier is read-only I can't change that! I made the path of compiler global (I add the path to Environment Settings, System Path) and in cmd works ! What to do ?

Comment: If it is added to path you may just use name `gcc` instead of full path. Programs are usually read only - this is not a problem, but user who runs your program may have restricted access to that directory, interesting...

Comment: Now works ! I made a batch file for the argumets with name `start.bat` and I don't need any Arguments!